# Can I read Griffiths and Purcell & Morin together?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education

I'm familiar with single variable, multivariable and vector calculus. Also the basics of ODEs. I know Special relativity at the level of **Morin's Classical Mechanics.** I have studied E&M before from Halliday, Resnick & Krane 5th edition. I want to embark on self studying E&M and in my research I have come across two canonical undergraduate books:

1. Griffiths (4th edition)
2. Purcell & Morin (3rd edition)

From what I have seen Purcell covers more topics at a less mathematical level than that of Griffiths.

**My question is can I profitably read the books side by side, working linearly through both of them?**

Because they both seem like exceptional books.

**Guess what I am really asking is are they suitable for being read together or do they have a very different organisation of topics?**

Answer (score 3):

They have a different approach to the subject, and also a different sequence of topics. Griffiths does not talk about special relativity until the very last chapter. Purcell beautifully shows the connection between the electric and magnetic fields in his fifth chapter. (It is one of the most beautiful chapters in all of the physics textbooks- literature, if not THE most beautiful!)

My suggestion would be to just read Griffiths, as he does things much more systematically. Purcell is for physical understanding, like the Feynman lectures. Once you are done with Griffiths, you can read Purcell rapidly to gain those precious insights.